# Beveled table frame

Tags: tables

I want to have diagonal/beveled corners in my table frame, which would look something like this:

```
   _____________________
  /                     \
 /                       \
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|      Dummy content      |
|                         |
|                         |
 \                       /
  \_____________________/
```

Here is the code I have so far (which just generates a table):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
            \hhline{~-~}
            /&&\textbackslash\\
            &Dummy content&\\
            \textbackslash&&/
            \hhline{~-~}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

This just outputs a table with slashes in the corners.

Comment: Hello. Could you post a (compilable) example showing your problem ? `/` should work in latex and `\backslash` too

Comment: Could you please add some background info on what ecaytly you cant to obtain? Is "Dummy text"  actually a table or literally just some twxt around which you want to draw a border? If it's the atter, there are better methods.

Comment: "Dummy text" is actually a "dummy table"

Comment: So, you want a table with an outer border that has rounded corners? Is this correct? If not, could you please add a sketch of teh desired output to your question?

Comment: Not rounded corners, but diagonal ones, ie. corners that are cut off, leaving diagonal lines behind.

Comment: As far as I know, `hhline` does not offer such a feature.

Comment: Is it possible to use another package that provides more options?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106284/discussion-between-someone-and-leandriis).

Comment: If  I understand correctly, you want a bevelled frame around a table?

Comment: Bevelled? What does that mean?

Comment: I think it's beveled, although I'm not sure

Comment: I think, using the `nicematrix` package, it should be quite easy to obtain this. But it would be helpful to get some idea of how the table should look like, so please consider providing an MWE. For more complicated frames, you should probably check the `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: How would I provide an MWE for something I don't even know how to make? That's…the point of the question.

Comment: @Someone Even if you don't know how to make the frame, you could provide a small test document including a table so people don't have to start from scratch. Instead you removed the little bit of code you had ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of changing the outline of the table, you could place the table in a `chamfered` shape from TikZ:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,chamfered rectangle,inner sep=-3pt] {\begin{tabular}{ccc}
                    a & b & c \\
                    a & b & c \\
                    a & b & c \\            
                \end{tabular}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]